# If there are data exist on the same rows of 2 columns OR there is data exist on one of the column, treats it as 1 case and sum

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a challenge that I mentioned in the above title. Suppose I have a "Total cases" cell (**E1**) to show the total value of cases in table **A1:C10**. If **B1** has data and **C1** is not (or vice versa), counts as 1 case. If **B2** and **C2** both have data, also counts as 1 case.

[image: The example]

In my actual case, there are a lot of rows that are **impossible** to determine the range, so I have to use the **COUNTA(B:B)** and **COUNTA(C:C)** to collect the total number of data that each column has. But after that, I haven't had any further clue to solve this anymore. I already did research on the **COUNTIF/COUNTIFS** and **IF** combination for this problem but I am still a noob with this.

Thank you for your reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words, you need a simple way to turn 2 into 1.

The [**SIGN() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sign-function-109c932d-fcdc-4023-91f1-2dd0e916a1d8) will do the job.

Try the formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN((B:B<>"")+(C:C<>"")))`

Comment: OMG!!!! You are a saint, thank you for your solution 

Answer (score 1):

You can also subtract the total number of rows from the number of rows that are all empty.

=ROWS(B1:B10)-SUMPRODUCT((B1:B10&C1:C10="")*1)

[image]

Comment: Actually, the all-empty case is also covered with the above JohnSun's solution, but I am really appreciated your support 