# Count 3 columns and sum the value in a column, exclude the result if data is not presented in 2 of 3 columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve:

[image: The example]

I have to calculate the total number of **Y** and **N** and show the total value in 2 separate cells (**B16** and **B17**).
The **D** column which contains **Y** and **N** is only counted when there is data presented in the **B** or **C** column.
As you can see from the picture, cell **D2** is not counted because there is no data in the **B** and **C** columns.

I am also the one who asks [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1750469/if-there-are-data-exist-on-the-same-rows-of-2-columns-or-there-is-data-exist-on) and have tried to advance the formulas that I was given in order to apply them to this problem. But again, I am still a noob with this :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep using the [**SUMPRODUCT() function**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e). Just add one more parameter, the following array - "cell equals x" or "cell equals h":

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN((B1:B14<>"")+(C1:C14<>""));N(D1:D14="Y"))
or
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN((B1:B14<>"")+(C1:C14<>""));N(D1:D14=A17))
```

Comment: won't it count rows twice where both B and C column contains information?

Comment: @MátéJuhász No, it won't, because `SIGN(1+0)=SIGN(0+1)=SIGN(1+1)=1`

Comment: @JohnSUN Man, thank you very very much. I'm also trying a lot to learn more Excel skills, people like you help the community grow and save noobs like me 

Answer (score 3):

I just created two helper columns, with following formulae:

```
=AND(D1="Y",OR(LEN(B1)<>0,LEN(C1)<>0)) // Column "E"
=AND(D1="N",OR(LEN(B1)<>0,LEN(C1)<>0)) // Column "F"
```

Then, I counted the amount of `TRUE` values in those columns:

```
=COUNTIF(E1:E19,TRUE) // result : 4
=COUNTIF(F1:F19,TRUE) // result : 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. In some situations, it's not allowed to use the helper columns, but through this workaround, it's easy to understand 